# Utilising SAS Token Authentication in Java SE client

Tags: java, eclipse, authentication, sas-token

I am writing a simple Java client that goes to a workspace server to retrieve some data. Workspace server does not allow public connections and the authentication mechanism is "SAS Token Authentication".

When I attempt to connect to the server, I get an error for invalid credentials. The same set of credentials work just fine when I attempt to connect to SAS Metadata server in Java code. I have full access to the workspace in questions in SAS EG.

SAS institute (I filed a support track) says that my connection needs to be SAS Metaserver aware, in other words I should have an active connection with SAS Metadata server and then connect with the same credentials to a workspace server of choice. The workspace server in turn will validate credentials against a list of active connections on Metadataserver.

I can do the first part no problem, I get a connection with metadata server going, but when I attempt to connect to a workspace server while maintaining  connection with metadata, my connection is denied saying username/password are incorrect.

I have used this sample code where I deleted methods for creating data tables/columns on metadata and instead put another method that starts a workspace factory with the same credentials after initiating a successful connection with metadata server, but before closing it. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/omaref/63063/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0zlnmq1vv8xgbn1hshp4rmw2btd.htm

I had posted this on LinkedIn where some suggestions were around token authentication, that I don't need to send a second set of credentials and I should obtain a token from metadata, use that to connect. The only reference to a token object that I found is on here: http://support.sas.com/rnd/javadoc/93/Foundation/com/sas/services/user/UserContextInterface.html#SHAREDRESOURCEKEY_ENVIRONMENT

Any general suggestions? Have I got something conceptually wrong here? Does anyone have a working sample of connecting to workplace server which uses SAS Token Authentication?

Regards,
Vasilij

Comment: You may want to cross post this on communities.sas.com, and/or search on github, there's a few power users who store their code on there.

Comment: Thanks Reese, that's a good idea, I will do that.